# Does the verb 'Christianize' require the capital 'C'? Why?

Tags: verbs

I have never come across any verb that **takes its first letter in capital.** It generally happens in *nouns.* I have read many books and in our schools also, the rules of making letter capitals is quite clear and understood. I have never come across any book that defines **capitalization of a verb**.  Nevertheless, here is the **verb** that is in capital!

> [Christianize (v)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/CHRISTIANIZE) - two meanings there.

I completely understand the meaning but why the verb has taken a capital letter? Is this the **special and only case?**

Is there any rule for a verb to have its first letter capital?

**Additional but useful note:** When Google has become immensely popular and the **verb** has formed from its noun, mind it, we changed 'G' to a *small letter*. You don't **[Google](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=google)** something, you **[google](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=google)** it.

Comment: I believe that words derived from proper nouns retain their capitalization. I usually see this with adjectives, not verbs (like _Victorian, Shakespearean, Euclidean, Rubenesque, Christmastime, Marxist_ and _Romantic languages_), but I didn't think part-of-speech affected the rule. Still, I'm at a loss to think of another verb! I tried _Anglicanize_ (not in most dictionaries) and _vulcanize_ (takes lower-case), before finally settling on [Hebraize](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hebraize), which isn't a great example, I'm afraid. Maybe not so many proper nouns become verbs?

Comment: @J.R. What about _italicize, bohemian, quixotic, china, guinea pig, utopia_?

Comment: @helix none of them take the capital letter as first.

Comment: @helix - Good examples. As can be expected, English is inconsistent at best. :^)

Answer (score 8):

You may think that if the root word *Christian* is capitalized then *Christianize* must be capitalized too. However, capitalization is a matter of usage and [it tends to change over time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10522/capitalisation-of-nouns-in-english-in-the-17th-and-18th-centuries).

---

Style guides  have disagreeing opinions.

> <sub>[From the U.S. Government Printing Office Style Manual](https://bulk.resource.org/gpo.gov/GPO_Style_Manual.pdf%E2%80%8E) 3.33 Religious Terms:</sub>
>
> Words denoting the Deity except who, whose, and whom; names for the
> Bible and other sacred writings and their parts; names of confessions
> of faith and of religious bodies and their adherents ... are all capitalized.
>
> *Christian; also Christendom; Christianity; Christianize*

On the other hand:

> <sub>[From the Chicago Manual of Style](http://archive.org/stream/manualofstylecom00univrich/manualofstylecom00univrich_djvu.txt)</sub>
>
> But do not capitalize verbs derived from proper names:
>
> *to boycott, to fletcherize, to christianize, to pasteurize.*

---

The question is: who's winning?

[image: Google NGram Viewer which shows the capitalized version has consistently been more common since about 1840]

Comment: *I would argue that capitalization is just matter of style. Only a few centuries ago, some people capitalized almost all nouns. The word Christanize is no exception.* - I had no problem if Christianize as a **noun** is capitalized. My question is capitalization of the **verb** Christianize.

Comment: @MaulikV I think I may have misrepresented my point— *editing to clarify*.

Comment: @MaulikV I'm a little confused because as far as I know, *Christianize* is always a verb, isn't it? (Although, admittedly, I'm not very familiar with the word.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. It is always a verb but the question is **why a verb takes its first letter capital.** Have you ever come across a verb that way?

Comment: If it's always a verb then I would follow the style manual I had to use. (helix provided two manuals of style already.) As for why or its etymology, though it's a part of your question, I'm not very concerned.

Comment: @MaulikV Addendum: ["Capitalization of proper nouns used as verbs"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/79041/24485)

Comment: @helix thank for the link but *Christianize* was **never** a noun I guess. Also, he has the same confusion and does not answer it - *...and especially seeing how English, in general, **simply does not capitalize verbs** except at the beginning of a sentence*

Comment: English, in general, doesn't capitalize verbs, but words related to diety (which would include _Christ_) provide exceptions to capitalization rules. From Wikipedia: "Many European languages traditionally capitalize nouns and pronouns used to refer to God, including references to Jesus Christ (reverential capitals): _hallowed be Thy name, look what He has done_. Some English authors capitalize any word referring to God: _the Lamb, the Almighty_; some capitalize 'Thy Name'. These practices have become less common in the 20th and 21st centuries." This is just a verb stuck in a gray area.

Answer (score 6):

This is not the "special and only case".  Oxford and Merriam-Webster both list *Africanize/Africanise* but not *africanize/africanise*.  I'm sure there are many more such cases; this just happens to be the first one that I thought of.

Answer (score 4):

Pre-1923 usage is mixed on whether to capitalize or not. Googlewhacking Gutenberg https://www.google.com/#q=christianize+site:gutenberg.org shows a definite mix of upper and lower case forms of the verb. I have not tried to further break down results by date of original publication, so it may have faded in or out of use.

WRT your G/google example I would note that you can "google" something using Bing (though few do) but you cannot Christianize people by preaching out of (say) a Torah or Koran. In that sense it is specific to Christ and his (His?) religion.

Comment: I first noticed examples of the generalization of the verb *google* more than ten years ago, but my current sense is that, for many (most?) speakers, it still refers to searching specifically with Google.

Comment: @snailplane Certainly, if you say *google it* it'll mean searching on Google only. Or else, to stay clear, I prefer *search on the Internet*. But there too, 'G' becomes 'g'!