# To Google something: capitalize or not?

Tags: style, capitalization

I have a small question about the usage of Google as a verb. Is it always capitalized, even as a verb? For instance:

> I Googled his name and I got hundreds of results.

Now, I am aware that this is a neologism and as such, it's probably not going to be in any dictionaries, but what is the most common usage for Google as a verb? It really looks strange to me to write or read "Googled", hence my question.

Comment: Did you try looking it up in a dictionary? Here are some results: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/google , http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/google. And here is an article about it: http://googlesystem.blogspot.ch/2006/07/google-is-officially-english-word.html

Comment: Oh, I thought it wouldn't be in any but it seems that English dictionaries are not as slow as Spanish ones! ;) Anyway, it seems to me that the capital G is preferred, yet Merriam-Webster lists "to google" rather than "to Google". Perhaps it's a bit of a divisive topic, isn't it?

Comment: I try not to say 'G/google' or 'P/photoshop' as verbs. There are other search engines and photo editing programs.

Comment: **Google** (the company) would prefer that you only use the verb form of 'google' to mean specifically using their search engine.  They'd also prefer that you capitalize it.  This is to prevent [Trademark Erosion and Genericization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genericized_trademark).

Comment: @Doc: No, they don't even want you to do that. Their "[Rules for proper usage](http://www.google.com/permissions/trademark/rules.html)" state: *Use the trademark only as an adjective, **never as a noun or verb**, and never in the plural or possessive form.*

Comment: @Cornstalks: As an *adjective*? I see that they write that, but it doesn't seem to make much sense ... according to that rule, a sentence such as "This is an absolutely Google search engine." would be allowable, whereas the sentence "In addition, Google may provide you with written requirements (...)." (from that very page) would not. That seems ... peculiar.

Comment: "and never in the plural or possessive form.", then, two bullet points later: "Use only Google-approved artwork when using **Google's** logos."  \*scratches head\*

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Unfortunately, there's no requirement that IP lawyers actually understand language when writing about it publicly.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Interestingly, the reason that your first sentence doesn't work isn't because of _Google_, but because of _absolutely_. _"This is a Google search engine"_ works completely fine, doesn't it? There are arguments over whether nouns acting as adjectives should be called adjectives, but if we say that adjectives describe some kind of property of the noun, then they are. Just consider that there are two types of adjectives: gradable (tall, hot) and non-gradable (Google, Facebook).

Comment: @jimsug: If *Google* is used as an adjective in the sentence *"This is a Google search engine."* then the question and answer pair *"How is this search engine?" - "It is Google."* would make sense, which seems to sound weird again. And even though you correctly state that some adjectives are non-gradable (in that they cannot be partially fulfilled), all adjectives can generally still be modified with adverbs that do not express the *level* to which they apply, but for example the *certainty* at which they apply - leading to the sentence *"This is an undoubtedly Google search engine."*

Comment: @jimsug: Interestingly, [this resource by the British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/adjectives-gradable-non-gradable) lists *absolutely* as an example of adverbs that can be used with *non-gradable* adjectives.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If it's an adjective, then you should be able to answer _What kind of search engine is this?_ _How is this search engine?_ is suitable for probing adverbs and complements, such as _This is a cold drink/This drink is cold_, not _This is a Google search engine/This search engine is Google_ (which works, but only because it sounds like you're introducing it). _undoubtedly_ is another way of grading the adjective, so it doesn't contradict my assertion: _this is an undoubtedly cold drink_ works, because _cold_ is gradable...

Comment: ... that resource is contradictory, and in that example, absolutely seems to be modifying the verb, not the adjective. You can't call an adjective non-gradable and then grade it, seems a bit silly. [Classifier](http://systemictheory.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/classifier-function.html) may be a useful term here, since using a noun in this fashion denotes a subclass, not a property.

Comment: @jimsug: When the question *What kind of search engine is that?* is applied to statements like *This is a search engine that belongs to Max.* or *This is a search engine by Sarah.*, the phrases *that belongs to Max* and *by Sarah* would qualify as adjectives just as well. As demonstrated by your example *This drink is cold.*, the question *How is this drink?* is suited to retrieve the adjective *cold* from the sentence.

Comment: @jimsug: Based on the definition from the beginning of the linked resource, *grading* of adjectives takes only place when the *degree* to which they apply is expressed. As you see, the examples there are consistent with that, as, in accordance with the definition, non-gradable adjectives are are modified only by non-grading adverbs such as *absolutely* or *completely*.

Comment: @jimsug: That said, you seem to be following the alternative approach of what constitutes a part of speech that is occasionally used in English, namely that the part of speech of a word is determined by the word's function and usage in the sentence. Inflection and possible combinations with other parts of speech, on the other hand, are largerly independent of the part of speech in that interpretation. Then, it is conceivable that *Google* in *Google search engine* is called an *adjective*, just like *search* in the same phrase, or the *bear* in a *bear trap*.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No. *Google* as a *verb* should not be capitalized. Because if you put 'G' capital, you mean the word 'Google' as a company (proper noun). You cannot *company* something.

I found this on Wikipedia. It's useful.

> The **first recorded usage of google** used as a *participle,* thus supposing an intransitive verb, was on July 8, 1998, by Google co-founder Larry Page himself, who wrote on a mailing list: "Have fun and keep **googling!**"
>
> Its earliest known use (as a transitive verb) on American television was in the "Help" episode of Buffy the Vampire Slayer (October 15, 2002), when Willow asked Buffy, "Have you **googled** her yet?"

There's no first letter capital.

OALD has an entry of the verb *[google](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/google).*

It's observed that when the tool of *doing something* becomes too popular (and omnipotent in its field!), its proper noun, over the period of time, becomes a *verb* and then the first capital letter is lowercased.

Another such proper nouns are --Photoshop, when used as a verb becomes *[photoshop](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/photoshop)* (no capital) and [Xerox](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/xerox_1), when used as a verb becomes *[xerox](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/xerox_2)* (no capital again).

On one [blog](http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2006/07/google-is-officially-english-word.html) (as fluffy says) it's written:

> The verb *"google"* (no capital) has been used in the recent years with the meaning "search (something) on the web", even though you use other search engine than Google (capital).

[**Generally,** a verb is not capitalized. However, the *only* verb with first letter capital I have come across is *Christianize*. [I had asked that question here on this board](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20791/does-the-verb-christianize-require-the-capital-c-why) some time ago.]

Noun and verb usage:

> Did you *google* this term? Vs. Did you search this term on *Google?* 
>   You can *photoshop* this image to make it better Vs. You can make this image better using *Photoshop.*

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you very much. I'm afraid I can't vote up just yet.

Comment: @PíoPío1949 thanks. That's okay. Your words say it all :) Good question though (+1). Many wonder this (including my teammates). But now they are convinced! :)

Comment: FYI, that link you posted is not to *Google's* blog: "This blog is not affiliated with Google."

Comment: As a point, Google (the company) states explicitly that you should **not** say that you are googling something *unless* you use the Google search engine.  This is due to trademark law - if 'Google' becomes ubiquitous to mean simply "search online" rather than specifically using Google, then Google would lose their rights to the word (it would become a [Generic Trademark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genericized_trademark)).  Coca-Cola went through a similar battle with "Coke", as did Xerox and Kleenex.

Comment: Of course, all of *coke*, *xerox*, and *kleenex* are now generic for many speakers.  *Google*, too, for some.

Comment: @Doc interestingly, in India nobody does photocopy. All do *xerox* and eight out of ten machines are not Xerox machines. They are of different manufacturers. Still it's xeroxing a document.

Comment: In the US, almost everyone "xeroxes" a document. I remember at IBM (who made copiers in competition with Xerox), they were very insistent that you "copy" or "photocopy" something -- using "xerox" too much could really hurt your career advancement. BTW, the generic process is called "_xerography_" (dry + writing), so it's not far off the mark to call it xeroxing.

Comment: @PhilPerry In Canada we always say that we "photocopy" something.

Comment: @MaulikV Thanks for dragging my name into this, but I think I didn't say anything in this question before. (You could remind me when I said it if I've said anything related to the quote, though.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. OMG. I have sighting of yours then lol. Sorry, it is fluffy. Extremely sorry.

Comment: @user54609, it would probably depend on how much market penetration and mindset share that Xerox achieved (at some point in the past). In the US it was very large for a while, so "xerox" = "photocopy" in most minds. In Canada, maybe Xerox never achieved dominance before competitors carved up the market among themselves.

Comment: Hmm I see. Yeah I don't recall seeing Xerox brand photocopiers a lot in Canada...or Kleenex brand tissues a lot either.

Answer (score 6):

Ignore people telling you what Google the *company* would like. Even with all their money to pay the best lawyers in the world, they're not going to affect the eventual position. They're currently holding the line...

[image: google]

...but it's a racing cert they'll end up following in the footsteps of [Heroin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/top-ten-lists/top-10-words-from-trademarks/heroin.html), [Aspirin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirin), and [Hoover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hoover_Company)...

[image: aspirin]

[image: heroin]

[image: hoover]

(The Hoover company was slow off the mark staking their claim to ownership of the *word*, so *Hoover the room* doesn't even occur often enough to graph.)

Personally, I tend to capitalise when I'm referring to things like *the Google results page, Google Books, Google NGrams*, etc., but not when it's just a verb (in which context I don't really care if I'm googling using a different search engine). Even if Google goes bust next year I expect that in a decade or two capitalising *to Google = to search on the Internet (perhaps using Google)* will be seen as "quaint".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "Aspirin" was seized as enemy property (from Bayer) during WWI, and put in the public domain. "Heroin" may have suffered the same fate (it was originally a pharmaceutical), but may have already been illegal by WWI. Do these ngrams exclude words capitalized because they are the first word in a sentence? Finally, to "hoover" a carpet is very rare in the US.

Comment: Well, interestingly, there are possibilities that the sentences **begin** with the word *Googling.* *(Googling is the simplest way to find information on anything)* and thus are capitalized. Also, in such cases, they serve as a noun and not a verb. The OP is quite specific about *to do (verb)* where capitalization is generally not observed.

Comment: @Phil, Maulik: Okay, I've changed the first NGram to only chart *verb* usages. It's still the same story - currently most people *do* capitalise, but I'm sure that won't last.

Comment: I don't see any clear trend in either direction (yet). About the same fraction of users capitalize over a long period of time.

Comment: @Phil: Absolutely! Which is why I think the top-rated answer here is potentially misleading (where's the sense in telling people that non-capitalising is "correct" when the majority are still doing that?). But we're talking about a very new usage here (unknown to most Anglophones even a decade ago). The point of *my* answer is I'm absolutely certain usage patterns *will shift significantly* over the next decade or two, and I've supplied other examples showing that's the general tendency (regardless of what Google, Inc.'s lawyers try to do about it).

Answer (score 6):

I searched the [*The Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)*](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) (1990-2012) for both `google` and `googling`, then used a script to count how many occurrences of each were capitalized.

Here's what I found:

```
  Googled   134       googled   17
  Googling  83        googling  19
```

So most occurrences (86%) in this corpus are still capitalized.  This, I think, reflects more conservative style.  You may wish to do the same—I certainly don't think it's *incorrect* to capitalize the verb.

However, when I repeat the experiment with [The Corpus of Global Web-Based English (GloWbE)](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/) using a random sample of 1000 results for each term, I find:

```
  Googled   284       googled   726
  Googling  385       googling  626
```

This is quite a different result!  Here, we find only 33% capitalization, as opposed to 86% in COCA.  My feeling is that this reflects less conservative usage.  Note that this corpus contains on average more recent usage, and that it doesn't have nearly as much copy-edited or formal content.

I believe it is now commonplace to write the verb *google* in lower case.  If you like, you may follow more conservative usage and capitalize it, but there is no particular need to do so.  My personal preference is for lower case.

Comment: True, leaving the term aside, it's obvious that we shouldn't capitalize it for two reasons. To avoid ambiguity and verbs are not capitalized - back to my concern of the word Christianize.

Comment: @MaulikV You are free to advocate your own prescriptive view in your own answer.  I prefer lower case, myself.  But since there are so many capitalized examples in the wild, it would be silly to say capitalizing it is actually incorrect.